# How to hide a paragraph of a single div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have a div which when i click expands, and i want that its paragraph show when it expands, i tried this in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).height() < 450){
            $(this).$('p').show();
            $(this).addClass('expanded');   
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('expanded');
            $(this).$('p').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

am i doing something wrong getting its paragraph?
sorry for bad english

Comment: `$(this).find('p')` instead of `$(this).$('p')` Also Show your HTML.

Comment: I think $(this).next('p') would work also, wouldn't it? Also you could look into the jQuery ui - it has an accordion widget that has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).height() < 450){
            $(this > 'p').show(); //change made here, assuming p is inside this element
            $(this).addClass('expanded');   
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('expanded');
            $(this > 'p').hide(); //change made here, assuming p is inside this element
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked with [Satpal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533/satpal) code:

```
$(this).find('p') instead of $(this).$('p')
```